# Can anyone look at this for me?

Tags: batch-file

I am making a game using .bat and I have run into some trouble. I want to create

```
echo Weapon=%wp%        HP=%hp%     ATK=%atk%       MP=%mp%     Gold=%gold%     Name:%uname%
echo -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

-

But I want to be able to have this in its own batch file. and use the call command to access it, but I need to be able to change each variable and each time I call this file it keeps a record of the new variable.

Comment: Passing values to another batch file is explained in the help for the `CALL` command.  Open up a cmd prompt and type `CALL /?` to read the syntax for it.

Comment: I need to see an example of it coded out.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the values as parameters to the sub-script (reference them there as `%1` for the first one etc.)

main.bat

```
@echo off
set wp=Sword
set hp=100
set atk=12
set mk=52
set gold=2
set uname=Travis
call sub.bat %wp% %hp% %atk% %mk% %gold% %uname%
```

sub.bat

```
@echo off
echo Weapon=%1        HP=%2     ATK=%3       MP=%4     Gold=%5     Name:%6
```

Alternatively you can use the variables from the main script (`call` opens a sub-process, which has inherits all variables from the calling process, but the calling process doesn't notice if they change in the sub-process):

main.bat

```
@echo off
set wp=Sword
set hp=100
set atk=12
set mk=52
set gold=2
set uname=Travis
call sub.bat %wp% %hp% %atk% %mk% %gold% %uname%
```

sub.bat

```
@echo off
echo Weapon=%wp%        HP=%hp%     ATK=%atk%       MP=%mp%     Gold=%gold%     Name:%uname%
```